# retina.js not swapping image?

Tags: javascript, image, retina.js

I'm having a bit of trouble using the retina.js script.  I'm trying to swap the logo for a retina image on this page:

http://mikeleachcreative.co.uk/comps/fmp-mobile/

The script is included as instructed and there are definitely images included with the required '@2x' extension, you can view these images here to make sure:

http://mikeleachcreative.co.uk/comps/fmp-mobile/images/fmp_mobile_logo.png
add @2x onto the end of the filename to see the high-res version.

When this page is viewed on a retina device, I am still seeing the lower-res image, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like (whenever the @2x image is checked) your server is returning 403 (not authorized).  Check the settings on your server.  Retina.js requires you to be able to make a HEAD request to the server (not GET or POST).